# Collection cannot be converted to Object[]

Tags: java, collections, treeset

Need help with a problem for a class! So I have created an array of names that gets passed to a method named runA in the class Proj04Runner. I need to create a TreeSet of these names to put them in naturally ascending order with no repeating values. However when I run my code, I get an error telling me that Collection cannot be converted to Object[].

```
import java.util.*;

class Proj04{
  static String[] names = 
  {"Don","don","Bill","bill","Ann","ann","Chris","chris"};
  
  static Object[] myArray = new String[8];
  
  public static void main(String args[]){

Proj04Runner runner = new Proj04Runner();

Random generator = null;
if(args.length != 0){
  System.out.println("seed = " + args[0] );
  generator = new Random(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
}else{

  long seed = new Date().getTime();
  System.out.println("seed = " + seed);
  generator = new Random(new Date().getTime());
}

System.out.print("Input:  ");
for(int cnt = 0;cnt < myArray.length;cnt++){
  int index = ((byte)generator.nextInt())/16;
  if(index < 0){
    index = -index;
  }
  if(index >= 8){
    index = 7;
  }
  myArray[cnt] = names[index];
  System.out.print(myArray[cnt] + " ");

System.out.println();

myArray = runner.runA(myArray);

System.out.print("Intermediate Results: ");
for(int cnt = 0; cnt<myArray.length;cnt++){
  System.out.print(myArray[cnt] + " ");

System.out.println();
```

}

```
        import java.util.*;
    
    class Proj04Runner{
        
        Object[] myArray;
        Collection ref;
    
        Proj04Runner(){
    
        public Collection runA(Object[] myArray){
            this.myArray = myArray;
            ref = new TreeSet();
            for(int ct = 0; ct < myArray.length; ct++){
                ref.add(String.valueOf(myArray[ct]));
            }
            return ref;
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: where exactly are you getting this error? and the return type for runA can be `Set` instead of Collection

Comment: Don’t use `Object[] myArray = new String[8];` If `myArray` is supposed to be a `String[]` array, declare it as such. When you use the type `String[]` consistently, instead of `Object[]`, there is no need to use `String.valueOf(myArray[ct])` as `myArray[ct]` is already a `String`. Further, you’re printing `"seed = " + seed`, but then, you’re not using `seed` but `new Random(new Date().getTime())` which may evaluate to a different value, as time has elapsed since the last `new Date().getTime()`. To pick a random name, just use `names[generator.nextInt(name.length)]`. And end the loop with `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Let's check the types:

- `myArray` is type of `Object[]`
- method `runA` takes one argument of type `Object[]` and returns `Collection`

The problem part is:

```
myArray = runner.runA(myArray);
```

Now we are supplying `Object[]` (`myArray`) to method `runner.runA()`, which is correct. On the other hand we are returning `Collection` and trying to assign it to variable of type `Object[]` (`myArray`), which is not correct.

### Solution

Now you have many options to solve this type madness.

Obvious two are:

- Make method `runA` return `Object[]` instead of `Collection`

  - e.g. `return ref.stream().toArray()`
- Make `myArray` type of `Collection` instead of `Object[]`

### Final notes

#### Do not use "raw" types

Instead of `Collection`, you say collection of what, e.g. collection of integers `Collection<Integer>` or collection of strings `Collection<String>`

#### `int cnt` is declared twice

Variable `int cnt` is declared two times in the same scope.